# Android MediaCodec dequeueInputBuffer always returns -1

Tags: android, audio, encoding, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

I'm trying to take raw data from the AudioRecord object and save it in a file using a MediaMuxer and MediaCodec.

I start the codec, start the muxer, load data into the input buffers and no such luck.

From debugging investigation, I've found that the problem is occurring in the call to `dequeueInputBuffer()`. It appears that the first few chunks of data succeed, but eventually `dequeueInputBuffer()` just returns `-1` constantly.

Is there something obvious that I'm missing? This seems like what's happening is I'm filling up the input buffers but they're never being released by the codec.

Snippet of relevant code:

```
int numChunks = input.length / CHUNKSIZE;
mAudioEncoder.start();
    for (int chunk = 0; chunk <= numChunks; chunk++) {
        byte[] passMe = new byte[CHUNKSIZE];
        int inputBufferIndex = -1;
        Log.d("offerAudioEncoder","printing chunk #" + chunk + "of " + numChunks);
        //Copy the data into the chunk array
        if (chunk < input.length / CHUNKSIZE)
            for (int i = 0; i < CHUNKSIZE; i++)
                passMe[i] = input[chunk * CHUNKSIZE + i];
        else {
            eosReceived = true;
            for (int i = 0; chunk * CHUNKSIZE + i < input.length; i++)
                passMe[i] = input[chunk * CHUNKSIZE + i];
        }

        //Get the input buffer
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            while(inputBufferIndex < 0)//justk keep trying.
                inputBufferIndex = mAudioEncoder.dequeueInputBuffer(100);
            inputBuffer = mAudioEncoder.getInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex);
        } else {
            //backwards compatibility.
            ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = mAudioEncoder.getInputBuffers();
            inputBufferIndex = mAudioEncoder.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);
            if (inputBufferIndex >= 0)
                inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
        }

        //Plop the data into the input buffer
        if (inputBuffer != null) {
            inputBuffer.clear();
            inputBuffer.put(passMe);
        }
        long presentationTimeUs = chunk * 10000000; //each encoded chunk represents one second of audio
        //this is what the frame should be labeled as
        mAudioEncoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, passMe.length, presentationTimeUs, 0);

        //Pull the output buffer.
        int encoderStatus = -1;
        while(encoderStatus < 0) //Like, seriously, WAIT forever.
            encoderStatus = mAudioEncoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(mAudioBufferInfo, -1);//wait forever, why not?
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
            outputBuffer = mAudioEncoder.getOutputBuffer(encoderStatus);
        else {
            ByteBuffer[] encoderOutputBuffers = mAudioEncoder.getOutputBuffers();
            outputBuffer = encoderOutputBuffers[encoderStatus];
        }

        if(encoderStatus >= 0) {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
                mMuxer.writeSampleData(audioTrackIndex, outputBuffer, mAudioBufferInfo);

            //Done with the output buffer, release it.
            mAudioEncoder.releaseOutputBuffer(encoderStatus, false);
        }//TODO: Add cases for what to do when the output format changes
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I figured it out. Ultimately I dumped the chunking logic and just increased the size of the input buffer by setting

audioFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE, 14000000);

For the MediaFormat object passed to the MediaCodec's configure method.

Also a good tip: Make sure to use 16-bit audio encoding and to use the AudioRecord.read method that spits out shorts. Bytes seem to produce screwy audio (probably because AudioRecord wants to be operating in 16 bit).